# How to grey out a Form Field in HTML

Tags: php, html

I am trying to grey out a form field in HTML such that the user cannot edit it, as it will be pre-populated. This is the code section with the issue:

```
<div class="element-input"><label class="title">Name</label><input value="<?php echo $data ?>"  class="large"  type="text" name="name" disabled/></div>
```

and when I render this in the browser, I see that it is pre-populated as planned and I cannot edit it, but when I submit it to the Database, it works and all values are inserted into the db except for the "name" which I suspect is due to the `disabled` attribute.

Is there anyway, that I can prevent the User from editing the field/grey it out and still have it inserted into the DB?

Comment: `readonly="readonly"` ? May need to add some CSS styling to *grey it out*.

Comment: In addition to this UI change, if you don't want the user to be able to edit that field, don't accept the form input for that field for the update. Just set it to the value you want it to have on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the readonly attribute:

```
<div class="element-input">
 <label class="title">Name</label>
 <input value="<?php echo $data ?>" class="large" type="text" name="name" readonly />
</div>
```

A read-only input field cannot be modified (however, a user can tab to it, highlight it, and copy the text from it).

By the way, sometimes it's handy to make a field readonly, and then remove the attribute with javaScript when some other condition is met.